# Adding totals from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and Eloquent on MySQL. Essentially I am trying to get results from invoices, including their 'total' and 'paid' amounts.

I have 4 tables:

invoices

```
id int(10),
date_due date,
client_id int(10),
deleted_at datetime
```

invoices_items

```
id int(10),
invoice_id int(10),
price decimal(15,2),
quantity int(10)
```

invoices_payments (this is a pivot table as payments can apply to other invoices too)

```
payment_id int(10),
invoice_id int(10),
amount decimal(15,2)
```

payments

```
id int(10),
payment_date date,
total decimal(15,2)
```

(there are other fields but they are not relevant)

I've been using this query, based on a few other answers and other research:

```
select 
    `invoices`.*, 
    SUM(
        invoices_items.price * invoices_items.quantity
    ) as total ,
    SUM(
        invoices_payments.amount
    ) as paid
from 
    `invoices` 
    left join `invoices_items` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoices_items`.`invoice_id` 
    left join `invoices_payments` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoices_payments`.`invoice_id` 
where
    `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null
limit 
    25
```

The problem I am having is that the result always only returns 1 row (there are 5 invoices in the test db), and the amount for 'total' or 'paid' is not correct.

I'd like to add that there may not be any records in `invoices_payments`

-- SOLUTION --

Here is the final query in case anyone runs into similar situation

```
select 
    `invoices`.*, 
    COALESCE(SUM(
        invoices_items.price * invoices_items.quantity
    ),0) as total, 
    COALESCE(SUM(invoices_payments.amount),0) as paid, 
    COALESCE(SUM(
        invoices_items.price * invoices_items.quantity
    ),0) - COALESCE(SUM(invoices_payments.amount),0) as balance 
from 
    `invoices` 
    left join `invoices_items` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoices_items`.`invoice_id` 
    left join `invoices_payments` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoices_payments`.`invoice_id` 
where 
    `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null 
group by 
    `invoices`.`id` 
order by 
    `balance` desc 
limit 
    25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY invoices.id` after the `WHERE`

Comment: I think I've been staring at this too long. Seems that did it.